# Deploy wcf web services on remote windows server 2008 with IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis-7

I have some questions on deploying wcf web services on IIS 7:

1. I don't  configure any endpoint or service in my *.cfg file, i enable only metadata and includeExceptionInFaults, but services are working properly on local server, when i debug application local IIS server some choose the port, endpoints. The questions is: will work web services without concrete configuration of endpoints / services, and this approach is good?
2. How to deploy application on a remote IIS 7 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. Without a endpoint configured, a WCF service is self sufficient to work. It will by default use basicHttpBinding and the address based on where you place in IIS.
   Refer to [Default end point of WCF service](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://saravananarumugam.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/default-end-point-of-wcf-service/&sa=U&ei=aaoUTqPrFcHagQeH2PT9BA&ved=0CBQQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNHCwdOZ1N4sQ8BLjbWBWgIMc7am-Q) for more detail.
2. For hosting in IIS, you can find a detailed walkthough in [How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)

Comment: Point 2 does **not** answer how can one **deploy** to **remote IIS**. This is not answer nor helpful.